# customer_account_create override not loading template

Tags: magento2, module, layout, template, overrides

I created a module Pera_CustomerRegistration, i want to override `/app/code/Pera/CustomerRegistration/view/frontend/template/form/register.phtml`

However, when i try to all i got is is an empty page with only the "Create New Customer Account" title, which makes me assume that the layout is overridden, but that the template is not loading.
Here is what i have so far.

customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="customer_account_create_head_components" template="Magento_Customer::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="Pera_CustomerRegistration::form/register.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="registerSubmitButton" xsi:type="string">.action.submit</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer" template="Magento_Customer::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And here is how the files are in the structure:

[image]

Also, here is my module.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Pera_CustomerRegistration" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>           
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>  
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

[image]

If you need any more info, please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to just keep below code inside your `customer_account_create.xml` file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
            <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register" template="Pera_CustomerRegistration::form/register.phtml" />          
    </body>
</page>
```

Your view file location at this place,

**`You have remaining 's' inside template folder name`**

Please replace **`template into templates`**,

```
/app/code/Pera/CustomerRegistration/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml
```

Clear cache and check.

Comment: It didn't work. I added your code, cleared cache and reloaded. However i still get a blank page ( i'll attach a screenshot on the question ).

Comment: you have problem in your module please replace template with templates.